# Extract subtitle by language code via ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle, video-subtitles

I have a simple task - extract subtitle for exact language from tvshows.
For example, I want to extract English subtitles from Netflix's show.
As you know there're a few different types of subtitles: forced, full and SDH.
So I want to extract all of them if it has eng language code.

To extract 1 subtitle from file I used this code for windows:

```
FOR %%i IN (*.mkv) DO (ffmpeg.exe -i "%%i" -map 0:s:m:language:eng -c copy "%%~ni".eng.srt)
```

It worked fine with 1 english subtitle per file. But if it contains 2, ffmpeg shows error

> SRT supports only a single subtitles stream

---

MI is...

- Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: subrip
- Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: subrip
- Stream #0:4(ara): Subtitle: subrip
- ...

---

So I should set 2 or more output files. I tried to figure out how to do this and found similar threads on reddit and stacksoverflow. They said there's no way to do this without ffprobe.
So I used ffprobe to parse all subtitle tracks and their language code.

```
FOR %%i IN (*.mkv) DO (ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams s -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -of csv=p=0 -i %%i > subs.txt)
```

File contains this info:

- 2,eng
- 3,eng
- 4,ara
- ...

---

As I understand I should use integers and set them values 2 and 3. I want to get output like this

> - MovieName.2.eng.srt
> - MovieName.3.eng.srt

If it easier to extract all subs, let it be. I tried to do this too but I dont know how to set integers and use them:(
So what I should do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the next unfortunate soul that has to deal with this, I changed this part:

```
-map 0:s:m:language:eng
```

into this:

```
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng
```

and it worked out fine, so it is worth a try.